# Merge two layers with transparent BG in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two layers in Photoshop. Layer one has Soft Light blend mode and 50 % opacity, and layer two has normal blend mode and 100% opacity.

When I merge these two layers, color of the picture on layer one changes.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

I added the background after the merge to see the result more clearly.

How can I merge these layers without any change in Photoshop?

Thank you

Comment: If you add a small version of the PSD file it will be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rasterise the first layer which has 50% soft light
2. Convert it to smart object by selecting the layer>Right click>Convert to SmartObject
3. Do the same to the next layer
4. Select both layers and merge.

Hope this work for you.

Cheers